# Python 3.6 API request - JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error

Tags: python, api, python-requests, python-3.6

When I make this API call (using Python 3.6):

```
main_api = "http://xyz:944/connector/reportqueries/routing/history/2.0/jobs?"
startTime='2019-02-19 01:01:01.001'
response = requests.get(main_api+"startTime="+startTime)
response.json()
```

I receive the following error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I get the same error when I call the full api path directly:

```
response = requests.get("http://xyz:944/connector/reportqueries/routing/history/2.0/jobs?startTime=2019-02-19 01:01:01.001")
```

However, when I paste this path directly into the browser, I receive plenty of data. What could cause this discrepancy?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z5QE.png)

Comment: That's an XML file. XML is not JSON. However, XML can be converted into JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the help.